# How do I define an intelligent xPath based on unique value contained in non-unique XMLTags for use with the XmlNode.SelectNodes() method in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I have an XML structure:

```
<Node>
    <SubId> 15 </SubId>
    <SubParam> someValue </SubParam>
</Node>
<Node>
    <SubId> 19 </SubId>
    <SubParam> someValue </SubParam>
</Node>
<Node>
    <SubId> 22 </SubId>
    <SubParam> someValue </SubParam>
</Node>
```

I want to select node if the SubId tag within that node has value 15.

My current code:

```
if (xPath.Contains("Node"))
{
    XmlNodeList fieldsToTest = root.SelectNodes(xPath);
    foreach (XmlNode field in fieldsToTest)
    {
        if (field.SelectSingleNode("SubId").InnerText.Equals("15"))
        {
          do something;
        } 
    }
}
```

Is there a way to directly select the Node in which SubId is "15" without selecting all Node elements and then iterating through the list? My guess is there must be a way to define a intelligent xPath for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following expression:

```
XmlNodeList fieldsToTest = root.SelectNodes("//Node[normalize-space(SubId) = '15']");
```

This should select the first `Node` element of your sample XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this XPath:

```
//Node[SubId = 15]
```